# Split string between words and quotation marks

Tags: java, regex, split

I currently have this string:

```
"display_name":"test","game":"test123"
```

and I want to split the string so I can get the value `test`. I have looked all over the internet and tried some things, but I couldn't get it to work.
I found that splitting using quotation marks could be done using this regex: `\"([^\"]*)\"`. So I tried this regex: `display_name:\":\"([^\"]*)\"game\"`, but this returned null. I hope that someone could explain me why my regex didn't work and how it should be done.

Comment: This looks like JSON... Can't you use a JSON parser???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to include the `"`,comma before `"game"` and also you need to remove the extra colon after `display_name`

```
display_name\":\"([^\"]*)\",\"game\"
```

**or**

```
\"display_name\":\"([^\"]*)\",\"game\"
```

Now, print the group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fK3yA5/2)

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"display_name\":\"([^\"]*)\",\"game\"").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it easier, [like this](https://regex101.com/r/hP8zD7/2):

```
/(\w)+/g
```

This little regex will take all your strings.

---

Your java code should be something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\w)+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourText);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

---

I also want to note as @AbishekManoharan noted that it looks like JSON